# Access denied for user ''@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, macos

Hi guys i've  been stuck on this issue for the past hour. I've read online that i have to change the privileges for the user on mysql. I have done this and the user has been granted all privileges yet i still get the error! when i enter `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';` it returns with

`+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+`
Any help would be much appreciated i just cant seem to find anything that works.

Comment: `Access denied for user ''@'localhost'`

which means username is **null**. Please clarify if you are getting `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Comment: yes for the root user

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not providing a user - ''@'localhost'. It's also difficult to troubleshoot with no code examples provided.

Comment: `<?php
$servername="127.0.0.1";
$username="root";
$password="";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

mysql_select_db("data") or die('Error' . mysql_error());
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} ` this is just the connection code

Comment: try: <?php $servername="localhost";

Answer (score 0):

Localhost and 127.0.1 are not treated the same for connection to mySQL so just change the $servername to localhost or grant privileges to root@127.0.0.1

From the docs:

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file. This occurs even if a --port or -P option is given to specify a port number. To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the local server, use --host or -h to specify a host name value of 127.0.0.1, or the IP address or name of the local server. You can also specify the connection protocol explicitly, even for localhost, by using the --protocol=TCP option.

Answer (score 0):

So it is,

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

But again you are not providing the complete information, Check which one of these two you are getting, We will provide next steps based on that

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: Yes)
```

Also, if you are not able to login mysql prompt as root, how then you are able to see `SHOW GRANTS` ?